# Control where liquibase DATABASECHANGELOG tables are created on Z/Os

Tags: db2, liquibase

I'm testing using liquibase for DB2 on Z/Os.  I have created several TEST databases running in their own table space.  When I run liquibase, it applies my changes but it creates the DATABASECHANGELOG table in SYSDEFLT storage group.

Is it possible to designate where the databaseChangeLog tables are created?  Instead of creating them in the SYSDEFLT storage group we would like to designate a user database for them.

Comment: You can create those table manually before running Liquibase the first time, then you have full control on where the data is stored.

Comment: We manually created the tables where we wanted so they would not be generated in the system catalog and this seemed to work fine.  I was unable to determine the correct command line parameters to control where we built the DATABASECHANGELOG tables.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. How you do it depends on how you run liquibase.

From the command line, either pass arguments or set the arguments in a liquibase.properties file.

The properties are `liquibase.databaseChangeLogTableName` and `liquibase.databaseChangeLogLockTableName`

If you are using other ways of running Liquibase, it will be similar.

Comment: These properties seem to control the name.  Do I use the following in order to change the location?   _"With 3.x there is the changelogCatalogName and changelogSchemaName attributes you can use in maven to control where the databaseChangeLog table goes."_   Further is sound like I have to pass these as -D<property.name>=<property.value>. for command line excution since I am not using maven. Is this correct?

Comment: In further conversations with our Z/os DBA,  she states that is is creating the tables in the catalog volume and she wants to be able to specify the DB.  She is trying to create the tables in the correct space manually, but curious if it is possible fro m the command line. From the Z/os console it displays for auto generated tables with the correct DB name, the correct schema, but the DB name needs to be specified.

Comment: If you are using Maven, I think you should be able to use either the "-D<property.name>=<property.value>" syntax OR set properties in your POM . I do not understand your second question. I do not know anything about the details or inner working of Z/OS or Liquibase on that platform.